# Will you cache some list from database into php array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few "key => value" Option List store in database (MySQL)
for example status, type, main category's Name
They seems like need to query maybe 6~10 time per pages.

So I start think to cache them as array in php file.
write a function whenever the optionList is updated, update the php file also.

When will you thing caching data like this case is good ?
I will try to measure the time spend and see which spend less 
(sounds like query speed VS read file speed), 
Besides that what else factor should be considered ?

Comment: yes you are accessing it _many_ times, so it's a good idea, especially if the data doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Caching is always good on data that is being read a lot but doesn't need constant updates. Even if it's being updated caching might still play a good part in your site design but can get a little more complex with managing states of data and expiration times.

It's worth looking for a caching framework (or an ORM). I don't have experience with these in PHP but some Googling should help.